# Sequelize update ignores invalid column names

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When I try to update a certain entry in the db, sequelize - Model.update() ignores the wrong column name passed to it. Say my table has columns 'id' and 'password', if I pass an object that has 'id' and 'pwd' to the update function, the 'pwd' is simply ignored and 'id' is updated.

Is there a way, through sequelize, to check if an invalid column name is being passed to the update function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a custom instance function to your Model via `prototype` to be able to access `this` to pass up to `this.update()` if your checks pass.

```
const MyModel = sequelize.define(
  'table_name',
  { ...columns },
  { ...options },
);
MyModel.prototype.validatedUpdate = async (updates, options) => {
  // get a list of all the column names from the attributes, this will include VIRTUAL, but you could filter first.
  const columnNames = Object.keys(MyModel.attributes);
  // the keys from the updates we are trying to make
  const updateNames = Object.keys(updates);

  // check to see if each of the updates exists in the list of attributes
  updateNames.forEach(updateName => {
    // throw an Error if we can't find one.
    if (!columNames.some((columnName) => columnName == updateName)) {
      throw new Error(`The field ${updateName} does not exist.`);
    }
  });

  // pass it along to the normal update() chain
  return this.update(updates, options);
}
module.exports = MyModel;
```

Then use it like this:

```
try {
   const myInstance = await MyModel.findById(someId);
   await myInstance.validatedUpdate({ fake: 'field' });
} catch(err) {
   console.log(err); // field does not exist
}
```